# How to detect a tile that is correctly returned by Tile Server but says "no map data"

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I know about the Leaflet Tile Layer's `tileerror` event, but it does not fire if the tile is just a dummy one with 'No map data' disclaimer on it.

```js
var map = L.map("map").setView([52.21581894148382, 2.74709701538086], 14);

var layer = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
 attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
});

layer.addTo(map);

layer.on("tileerror", function() {
  console.log("An error occurred while trying to load a tine...");
});
```

```css
#map { height: 98vh; }
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

 <div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a Tile Server that sometimes returns a technically correct tile image, but its content says that there is actually no useful data rendered on it, like that one:

[image: Example of tile without useful rendered data]<sub>Tiles © Esri — Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community</sub>

You would like to be notified when the Leaflet Tile Layer gets such a tile, in a similar way as the [`"tileerror"`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#gridlayer-tileerror) event.

Since the tile is technically correct, unfortunately Leaflet has no way to understand that there is actually no useful data rendered on it.

However, you could very well perform an image comparison with a tile you know has no data on it, assuming that the Tile Server always returns the exact same content.

1. Listen to the Tile Layer's [`"tileload"`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#gridlayer-tileload) event to attach a callback whenever a new tile has been loaded.
2. Compare the tile image with the one you know corresponds to "no useful data" state. E.g. you could use [js-imagediff](https://github.com/HumbleSoftware/js-imagediff/), but there are many other libraries for such a task.
3. Perform some action if images are equal, e.g. fire a new event.

(open your browser developer console to see the effect of the below code snippet)

```js
var map = L.map("map").setView([52.21581894148382, 2.74709701538086], 14);

var layer = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
  attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community',
  crossOrigin: true // Required to be able to analyze the image in a canvas context.
}).addTo(map);

var nodatatile = document.getElementById('nodatatile');

// 1. Listen to the Tile Layer's "tileload" event.
// http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#gridlayer-tileload
// http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#tileevent
layer.on('tileload', function(tileEvent) {
  var tile = tileEvent.tile;
  var c = tileEvent.coords;
  // 2. Compare the tile with a known tile that has no useful data.
  // https://github.com/HumbleSoftware/js-imagediff/
  var isEqualToNoData = imagediff.equal(nodatatile, tile);

  // 3. Perform some action if they are equal, e.g. fire a new event.
  if (isEqualToNoData) {
    layer.fire('tilenodata', tileEvent);
  }
});

// Listen to the new event.
layer.on('tilenodata', function(tileEvent) {
  var c = tileEvent.coords;
  console.log('Tile no data at ' + c.x + '/' + c.y + '/' + c.z);
});
```

```css
#map {
  height: 98vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagediff@1.0.8/imagediff.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>

<img id="nodatatile" src="https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/14/5395/8316" crossorigin="" />
```